# A manga about a girl who goes back in time through a door to be with a guy who died

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, isekai

A girl is sad about her best friend’s death, a guy, and she reads his diary. In it, he says all the things he wished he could do but didn’t due to his terminal illness. She goes through this door in a house on the floor, I think, and she’s back in the past.

She sees her friend and tells her past self to do these things. She’s back in the present with him dead, but she has new memories and his diary says he fell in love with her and he’s thankful for her help. I remember they climbed a mountain he couldn’t at the field trip before.

So after looking at a few thousand profiles of something that might be what I’m looking for, I think (emphasis on think) the blurb said the girl saved him from being bullied but he didn’t need help. This might be part of a different manga but hopefully it isn’t. I also recall he meeting him in the past on the bus? My memory is so foggy but this manga is lowkey vivid.
Possible a one-shot.

Comment: You have tagged this as an isekai, does this mean that the main character is going to a different world? or is this just that she time travel to the past?  based on the description you gave, it sounds like it is just time travel instead of an isekai.

Comment: Isekais are when a character gets a chance at a “second” life whether that be in a different world or their original one. From what I remember, I think the girl keeps her memories are relives these years. Therefore this could be an isekai.

Comment: I've never heard that definition for isekai.  The definition I know is that a character has traveled to a 'different world', that world can be fantasy, virtual, or a parallel universe, but it is explicitly not the world they came from.  It is also the definition i'm seeing looking online.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isekai

Comment: I looked at the page, it says fantasy or parallel world. Thus would literally be a parallel world. If the girl changed the past, she created a different timeline which means she lived a different life in a separate world.

Comment: I disagree, since she was not "transported to, reborn or otherwise trapped" in another world or timeline.  She went to the past of her timeline.  The fact that her actions changed the timeline afterwards does not mean that she traveled to another world.  It was still her past when she did the time travel.

Comment: That’s the part I don’t remember, I don’t know if she told her past self to do this stuff, or if she stayed in that time herself alongside her past self. I’d rather be safe than annoyed asf. I will say, if the timeline is different, that means the world itself is not the same due to stuff like the butterfly effect. I do know she didn’t have control when she traveled and when she returned, I think it just happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*100% Gokuama Kareshi*, Chapter 3

Finally found this one. It is a one shot, it was not from the deleted list of recommendations, they do meet off the bus but there’s scenes on. They were not best friends but likely close peers, there was a mountain, the room was a shrine not a house, and the diary was told to be thrown away but the mom gave it to the mc. It wasn’t really sad but I’m happy I found it again and I read it.

Comment: Congrats on finding it. And thank you for coming back to not only provide the answer, but to provide some details of how it matches. You can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].